# JQuery Add Class To Parent Object

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am trying to add a class of 'active' to a parent list item if one of it's children has the class 'active'.

Current html:

```
<ul class="top">
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Link1</a>
    <ul class="drop">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

current JQuery:

```
if($('ul.top li ul.drop li').hasClass('active')) {
            $('ul.top li.parent').addClass('active');
    }
```

​

​

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/FmT52/ to view how far I have got.

I have managed to half do it but only so far as using Jquery to add the class of 'active' to all top level list items.

As ever, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried `$('ul.top li ul.drop li').hasClass('active')(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}` but no luck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over all the `li's` and add the class to the `closest parent ul`

```
$('ul.top li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.closest('li.parent').addClass('active');
    }        
});
```

**[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FmT52/9/)**
​

Answer (score 3):

try with this one:

```
$('li.active').parent().closest('li.parent').addClass('active');
```

checkout the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/FmT52/8/**

Answer (score 0):

You can do simpler :

```
 $('ul.top li.parent:has(.active)').addClass('active');
```